# Reading IPTC information with C#, .NET Framework 2

Tags: c#, iptc

is there any possibility to read the IPTC information of a picture with C# and the .NET Framework 2?

I haven't found any solution. Only with .NET Framework 3.0 oder .NET 3.5 you can do it.

Any help, any information?

Thank you very much from Germany!
 Stephan

Comment: Just to clarify - re the 3.0/3.5 - is this using WPF?

Comment: As far as I know the 3.0/3.5 are using the WPF for reading the IPTC information. And the WPF is _not_ avaiable for the 2.0.

Comment: Is there any general solution for using 3.0/3.5 features under 2.0?

Comment: Yes. Upgrade. There's no reason not to do it. .NET 3.0 and 3.5 are additive. They do not replace .NET 2.0. They simply apply two service packs - to .NET 2.0 SP2. You also don't need Visual Studio 2008 to upgrade. You can just upgrade the Framework.

Comment: Are there any risks or side effects to upgrading a Windows 2003 server which runs some custom software which is built on .NET 2.0? Can I just apply updates and restart?

Comment: This IPTC technical specification may be useful: https://www.iptc.org/std/IIM/4.1/specification/IIMV4.1.pdf

Answer (score 3):

OK, my previous answer was a little 'confused'. Here is a link to a .NET 2.0 project (Visual Studio 2008 SLN format) that provides some basic 'extraction' functionality [MetaExtractor ZIP (25Kb)](http://deepzoompublisher.com/TagUpdater/MetaExtractor_v0.1.zip)

CODE SNIP:

```
// The Parser class extracts the data to hardcoded properties.
// it's 1200 lines - too many to post on StackOverflow
JpegParser parser = new JpegParser(path);
if (parser.ParseDocument())
{
    Console.WriteLine("Parsed {0} {1}", System.IO.Path.GetFileName(path), parser.Title);
    Console.WriteLine("Tags: {0}", parser.KeywordString);
    Console.WriteLine("Description: {0}", parser.Description);
    Console.WriteLine("Title: {0}", parser.Title);
    Console.WriteLine("Rating: {0}", parser.Rating);
}
```

USAGE:

```
MetaExtractor "C:\Users\Craig\Pictures\anton-1.jpg"
```

OUTPUT:

```
 == DeepZoomPublisher MetaExtractor v0.1 ==
Parsed anton-1.jpg Beach Photo
Tags: beach, blue sky
Description: Anton
Title: Beach Photo
Rating: 3

Press any key to exit...
```

Hope that helps more than my previous answer.

Answer (score 2):

I realize this answer does not address .NET framework v2, but I thought it was worth documenting for those of you who are using .NET 3.5 or higher.  This might also work in 3.0 but I have not tested it there.

The following function call will return the keywords embedded in a JPEG image:

```
    private string[] GetKeywords(string filespec)
    {
        BitmapDecoder decoder = new JpegBitmapDecoder(new FileStream(filespec, FileMode.Open), BitmapCreateOptions.None, BitmapCacheOption.None);
        BitmapMetadata meta = (BitmapMetadata)decoder.Frames[0].Metadata;
        return meta.Keywords.ToArray<string>();
    }
```

The BitmapDecoder and BitmapMetadata class are contained in an assembly that is normally used in WPF, so you'll need to reference the following assemblies to use those classes:

- PresentationCore
- WindowsBase

I am successfully using this approach in a WinForm app, but I suspect it could be adapted for other application types.  Also, you can see that the abstract "BitmapDecoder" class in this example is assigned a JpegBitmapDecoder instance, but you could get an instance of another decoder for your image type (TIFF, GIF, PNG, BMP, and WMP are also supported).

Answer (score 1):

Stephan,

These two links should be useful

[Reading XMP metadata from JPEG](http://www.shahine.com/omar/ReadingXMPMetadataFromAJPEGUsingC.aspx)

[EXIF extractor (on CodeProject)](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/graphics/exifextractor.aspx)

They both access slightly different parts of the JPEG header to extract the various metadata that can be embedded. I have used their code in [Searcharoo (which you can download)](http://searcharoo.codeplex.com/) and to extract the lat/long from JPEGs for this [DeepZoom example](http://conceptdev.blogspot.com/2009/03/silverlight-virtualearth-map-control_23.html).

You can grab my `JpegParser.cs` class from this [13kb code ZIP](http://www.deepzoompublisher.com/TagUpdater/TagUpdater_v0.1_src.zip) - it only grabs a couple of properties (Title/Description/Keywords/Rating/Latitude-Longitude) but you should be able to see in the code where to extract more == SEE EDIT BELOW ==

**NOTE:** the hard work was all done by the authors of the two articles linked above.

**EDIT:** comment below highlight the face that the `JpegParser.cs` I referenced above includes a reference to `using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;` and `BitmapImage img = new BitmapImage(new Uri(filename));`. These were added as part of an (unfinished) enhancement, so they can be safely removed and the `JpegParser.cs` class should then run in 2.0 (although the containing project will not - sorry for the confusion).

Alternatively, you can get similar code (some editing will be required) from [JpegDocument.cs](http://searcharoo.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/20374#490868) class in [Searcharoo](http://searcharoo.codeplex.com/) - a .NET 2.0 application that indexes files (including JPEGs) for example this [search result](http://searcharoo.net/Search.aspx?searchfor=New%20York)

Comment: Your JpegParser.cs is using System.Windows.Media.Imaging, it references the PresentationCore assembly. Doesn't that mean that it won't work on .NET framework 2.0?

Comment: Ah sorry, I mixed up two different projects there. The TagUpdater code is 3.5; but is based on this Searcharoo class which is definitely 2.0-compatible
http://searcharoo.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/20374#490868
... I posted the link because it was a small, self-contained project but forgot about the WPF inclusion. Turns out the System.Windows.Media.Imaging and BitmapImage reference can be removed anyway - half-done I guess. Will update my post too.

Answer (score 1):

I have just searched almost the entire web to find a C# solution to extract IPTC information, and found this nice and brand new tutorial at Code Project:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/graphics/ReadingIPTCAPP14.aspx

Hope it helps someone. :)

Comment: The Photoshop Segment is APP13, not APP14 like the article suggests. Parsing JPEG, Photoshop resources and IPTC records using regexps also doesn't seem like a great idea.

Answer (score 0):

If it was implemented in 3.x, it was not present in earlier versions.

However, there are 3rd party libraries that can do the trick.  [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) is one of them.  If you are looking for a simpler (and free) implementation, this [article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/graphics/iptc.aspx) or a google search may lead you to a solution.

Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

Having tried several suggestions from here and elsewhere with no luck, I have settled on writing a class to call out to the exiv2 command-line tool. A small performance penalty for spawning a process for each image is acceptable in my scenario, it may not be in others.

- Call exiv2.exe using System.Process
- Pass arguments "-pi filename.jpg" to output all IPTC fields
- Read output using System.Process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
- The output can be split into its parts using Regex